# unable to pas derived List<>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting

I have

```
class A
{}

class B : A
{}
```

I also have a method that expects a List parameter

```
void AMethod(List<A> parameter)
{}
```

Why can't I

```
List<B> bs = new List<B>();
AMethod(bs);
```

And secondly what is the most elegant way to make this work?

regards

Comment: The elegant way is to download Visual Studio 2010 RC _right now_ and prove to yourself that this has been fixed with their support of covariance. Then wait a month until the launch.

Comment: @John Saunders: No, this wouldn't work even with .NET 4.0. Classes are invariant. It would work if AMethod took `IEnumerable<A>` instead though.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I'm actually bound to Visual Studio 2005 so .NET 4 isn't an option.

Comment: If you are bound to VS2005, I would say you need to find the person who tied the ropes, and gently ask to be untied..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the method signature generic like this:

```
void AMethod<T>(List<T> parameter) where T : A
{}
```

Or, you could wait for .NET 4 where this scenario is supported for IEnumerable<>

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to other answers, this *isn't* supported in .NET 4.0. Only interfaces and delegates support generic variance. However, .NET 4.0 *would* allow you to do this:

```
void AMethod(IEnumerable<A> parameter) {}
...
List<B> list = new List<B>();
AMethod(list);
```

In .NET 3.5 you can get much the same thing to work with the aid of `Cast`:

```
void AMethod(IEnumerable<A> parameter) {}
...
List<B> list = new List<B>();
AMethod(list.Cast<A>());
```

Another alternative is to make `AMethod` generic:

```
void AMethod<T>(List<T> parameter) where T : A
...
List<B> list = new List<B>();
AMethod(list); // Implicitly AMethod<B>(list);
```

That may or may not do what you need - it depends on what you do within `AMethod`. If you need to add new items of type `A`, you'll have problems - and rightly so. If you only need to get items *out* of the list, that would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx). There are some good explanations and examples (for the upcoming c# 4.0).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that generics do not support covariance; I have read that this is coming in 4.0

That is why you are not able to pass the list where base type is expected

http://www.boyet.com/Articles/CSharpCovarianceOne.html